# VSTS JPG Reduce Image pixels

Tags: azure-devops

I have images in my web project that when they are check-in the pixel changes from 183 to 100. Is there a setting so this will not happen?

Comment: Do you mean that the image pixels changes automatically once they are checked in source control in VSTS?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean the pixels changes automatically once checked in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test on my side, and cannot reproduce this issue. It will not change the properties if you just check in the images into VSTS repository.

Make sure the `Encoding` of the image file should be `Binary` .

Besides, industry best practice is not to store binaries in source control. The solution for that in the Visual Studio world is to use `NuGet`. Most of the third party components that you use will already be available on nuget.org and you should depend on those versions.

For images and other assets you should use your own `NuGet` repo. This can be as simple as a file share or MyGet/ProGet. Group your image assets into complimentary bundles as NuGet packages and use NuGet package restore to maintain them without checking in.